# How to use a command without being in the same directory

Tags: command-line

So for example if I would have to list all the files in bin.

If I were in /root/home/ and I wanted to list bin.

If I were in root I would use:

> ls bin

But how to use it from /home/username/

> ls /root/bin/

I tried to use the one above, but It didn't work.

Comment: There's no directory `/root/bin`, rather `/bin`

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is

```
ls /bin
```

More generally, the slash character "/"  without any leading characters references the root directory. i.e.

```
cd /
```

changes directories to the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

/root is the home directory owned by root, if you are root or prefix your command with sudo you can see files in /root

confusingly just / is called 'the root' of the filesystem.

/bin is where binaries are stored, like in the directory bin, /usr/bin and the ones reserved for root sbin and /usr/sbin

`ls /bin`

should work regardless the directory you're in.

and if you just quickly want to jump into the directory
`pushd /bin`

and when you're done
`popd`

and to switch between the directory you where last use
`cd -`